# How to add "lang" attribute in blogger template?

Tags: xml, blogger, lang

Hi am using Minima Colored 2 Responsive Template on my blog. I want to add "lang" attribute in  my blogger template. As you already know that blogger templates are in XML. So I am confused where to add lang attribute in XML and what's the code for that.

My blog url is http://electricalfreaks.blogspot.in. My blog's XML code starts with something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...........
</head>
...........
</html>
```

simply change `en` with your language code

Comment: Is lang="en" is applicable to both US English and British English as i have both in language in my blog. Or do i have to use two different code for each like this:- <html lang="en-US"> and one more time <html lang="en-GB"> @bl4ckbox

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html b:css='false' b:defaultwidgetversion='2' b:layoutsVersion='3' b:responsive='true' b:templateVersion='1.0.0' expr:class='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' lang="en" xml:lang="en"
xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>

<head>

</head>

</html>
```

and the last step is to change the "lang="en" xml:lang="en" with your language, for example, my site net3arabi is Arabic so I will make it "lang="ar" xml:lang="ar"